# Strong "Force Touch" feedback for normal clicks

Tags: macos, macbook, touchpad, osx-yosemite

On my new Retina MacBook Pro with the "Force Touch" trackpad, the click feedback feels disappointingly weak compared to the physical click of the old trackpad (and my Magic Trackpad). However, the "Force Touch" click feedback is excellent! I'd like to configure the trackpad so that the feedback for normal clicks is that powerful.

I've already configured the click to "firm" in System Preferences, but it's still very weak in comparison. Is there a `defaults` setting to configure the feedback, or can an app like BetterTouchTool be used?

There is a preferences file named `com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad.plist`, which seems like a possible candidate:

```
{  
   "TrackpadFourFingerHorizSwipeGesture":2,
   "TrackpadPinch":1,
   "USBMouseStopsTrackpad":0,
   "TrackpadFourFingerVertSwipeGesture":2,
   "ActuateDetents":1,
   "FirstClickThreshold":2,
   "SecondClickThreshold":2,
   "TrackpadTwoFingerDoubleTapGesture":1,
   "TrackpadHorizScroll":1,
   "TrackpadMomentumScroll":true,
   "TrackpadFourFingerPinchGesture":2,
   "TrackpadRotate":1,
   "Clicking":0,
   "TrackpadThreeFingerTapGesture":2,
   "TrackpadThreeFingerHorizSwipeGesture":1,
   "TrackpadScroll":true,
   "DragLock":0,
   "TrackpadFiveFingerPinchGesture":2,
   "ForceSuppressed":false,
   "TrackpadThreeFingerVertSwipeGesture":1,
   "TrackpadTwoFingerFromRightEdgeSwipeGesture":3,
   "UserPreferences":true,
   "version":7,
   "Dragging":0,
   "TrackpadRightClick":true,
   "TrackpadCornerSecondaryClick":0,
   "TrackpadHandResting":true,
   "TrackpadThreeFingerDrag":false
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I asked again the other day - typically for here, no one knows or cares. https://superuser.com/questions/1695472/increase-click-feedback-haptic-response-macbook-pro-14?noredirect=1#comment2607541_1695472

Answer (score 1):

Support for this exists in [Better Touch Tool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/), which is a wonderful little utility if you haven't tried it.

The settings for it are under `Advanced > Advanced Settings > Trackpad > FORCE Touchpad`, and there are a lot of options.

[image: Screenshot of the Advanced force touch feedback options]

Some of them feel really odd. But I've found that's a good thing if you have certain types of gestures set up. For instance, If you have a special gesture for a four-finger click at the "bottom" of the trackpad, it can be difficult to know if you hit the right area, or if it detected your thumb as a finger, etc. That uncertainty is squashed when you feel the `Double Light Feedback`, which only occurs when BTT is handling the gesture, and does not occur under normal system gestures, like say, a single-finger or two-finger click.

Hope that helps.

Comment: BTT's settings only affect its own gestures. The settings you point out do not change global settings, so this won't do what the OP requests.