# Increase click feedback (haptic response) Macbook Pro 14"

Tags: macbook, touchpad

I'm trying to get a stronger click out of my trackpad. I want a real crunch, like the physical click on my old 2015 Macbook Air. Picking up where this question left off:
[Strong "Force Touch" feedback for normal clicks](https://superuser.com/questions/920734/strong-force-touch-feedback-for-normal-clicks)

I've found that setting click strength to "Light" in System Preferences > Trackpad sets the following values in com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad.plist

`FirstClickThreshold: 0`
`SecondClickThreshold: 0`

Setting the preference to "Firm" changes both those values in the plist to `2`.

But setting those values manually higher than 2 doesn't seem to give a firmer-than-firm click. Has anyone figured out a way to get stronger feedback for normal clicks?

Comment: Probably this is just not intended and 2 is the highest value that the trackpad driver can make sense of.

Comment: It's the same on an iPhone, three values only.

Comment: Do you know if this is in the firmware, or might there be some way to play with the driver?